# Azure SQL Database IP Firewall Rules - Restrict access to mi private network IPs

Tags: azure, firewall, rules

thanks in advance

I have the following scenario:

- SQL database on a SQL Server on premise (source)
- SQL database on aAzure (target)
- I access to my network from a VPN (F5 - Big IP Edge Client)
- I created and configured an Azure VPN Gateway to connect to the VPN. With this configuration and the use of Azure Data Factory, it is possible to see my on-premise database and read the data.

I want to restrict access to the Azure SQL database only to clients from my on-premise network (or connected to the VPN). When i try to set the firewall ip rules, Azure only allow to register public ips address but not recognice IPs from my onpremise network.

**Questions**
1)It is possible to set access to only clients from insede my private network. How to get this?
2)Is there another better option to get this secure connection?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure maintains a firewall for the SQL Azure servers, preventing anyone from connecting to your server if you do not give their IP address permissions. Permissions are granted by client IP address. Any user’s desktop application that connected to SQL Azure would need to have the SQL Azure firewall open for them in order to connect. The client IP would be the IP address of the desktop machine as seen by the Internet.

Any desktop computer can access SQL Azure as long as it has Internet access, and port 1433 open for outbound connections.

If you're trying to connect from within a corporate network, you can add user machine public IP or the VPN endpoint IP if all user connect through it. Further to allow access from specific on-premises machines, firewall rules can be used to limit connectivity only to your public (NAT) IPs.

A more secure option, you can set up server-level firewall rules (Server-level IP firewall rules apply to all databases within the same server) and Setup database firewall rules (Database-level firewall rules only apply to individual databases,  can be configured using Transact-SQL statements, and only after you've configured a server-level firewall rule.)

- Create server-level and database-level firewall rules
- Configure an Azure Active Directory (AD) administrator
- Manage user access with SQL authentication, Azure AD authentication,
  and secure connection strings
- Enable security features, such as Azure Defender for SQL, auditing,
  data masking, and encryption

Refer: [Create firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/secure-database-tutorial#create-firewall-rules) & [Configure your client computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#configure-your-client-computers)